# Как вывести температуру GPU с помощью GPUtil Python

Tags: python, gpu

Следующий код выводит параметры видеокарты, в том числе температуру в виде таблицы. Как вывести значение температуры GPU отдельным числом? В документации ничего не нашел.

```
import GPUtil
GPUtil.showUtilization(all=True)
```

Comment: Ну не знаю, я в документации вполне увидел функцию getGPUs — `print(GPUtil.getGPUs()[0].temperature)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `showUtilization` умеет только печатать данные на экран. Получить состояние всех `GPU` в виде цифр, с которыми можно потом что-то делать, можно так:

```
# !pip install GPUtil
import GPUtil

print('GPU temperature')
for gpu in GPUtil.getGPUs():
    print(f'{gpu.id}: {gpu.name} - {gpu.temperature}')
```

Вывод в `Google Colab` с включённым `GPU`:

```
GPU temperature
0: Tesla K80 - 33.0
```

P.S. Я даже не смотрел в документацию. Просто набрал в интерактивном питоне `GPUtil.` и посмотрел, какие варианты даёт контекстная подсказка. Ну и дальше тоже самое с конкретным `GPU` - взял первый элемент из списка, записал в отдельную переменную `gpu`, ввёл `gpu.` и снова посмотрел контекстную подсказку.